# Tensorflow Dataset API how to order list_files?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using the Dataset API `list_files` in order to get  a list of files in a `source` directory and `target` directory, something like:

```
source_path = '/tmp/data/source/*.ext1'
target_path = '/tmp/data/target/*.ext2'
source_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(source_path)
target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_path)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((source_dataset, target_dataset))
```

Source and target dir contents have same sequential filenames, but different extensions (e.g, source 0001.ext1 <-> target 0001.ext2).

But since list_files is not ordered in anyway, the zipped dataset contains missmatches between the source and the target.

How can I solve this within the new dataset API?

Comment: Sorting is, as of october 2017, not supported in datasets. Since there aren't that many files, however, you can build a sorted list of filename pairs in python and make a dataset from a tensor out of that list.

Comment: # According to the docs   |                                                                 NOTE: The default behavior of this method is to return filenames in a non-deterministic random shuffled order. Pass a seed or shuffle=False to get results in a deterministic order.  |                                                                        So, you may try the same seed value for source and target dataset and check if that's working.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of this method is to return filenames in a non-deterministic random shuffled order. Pass a seed or shuffle=False to get results in a deterministic order.

```
source_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(source_path, shuffle=False)
```

or

```
val = 5
source_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(source_path, seed = val)
target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(data_path, seed = val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by sorting the file paths first.

My files are named like in OP's case:

```
input image       -> corresponding output
data/mband/01.tif -> data/gt_mband/01.tif
data/mband/02.tif -> data/gt_mband/02.tif
```

The code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow as tf

DATA_PATH = Path("data")

# Sort the PATHS
img_paths = sorted(map(str, (DATA_PATH / 'mband').glob('*.tif')))
mask_paths = sorted(map(str, (DATA_PATH / 'gt_mband').glob('*.tif')))

# These are tensors of PATHS
# Paths are strings, so order will be preserved
img_paths = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_paths)
mask_paths = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mask_paths)

# Load the actual images
def parse_image(image_path: 'some_tensor'):
    # Load the image somehow...
    return image_as_tensor

imgs = img_paths.map(parse_image)
masks = mask_paths.map(parse_mask)
```